# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/unauthorized-domain). error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I try to open google sign-in in the deployed version of my app I get this error in the console and the popup closes. I have googled a bit about this error and I found that I need to add the domain in my firebase through `Authentication -> SignIn method ->Authorized domains` and then add the domain I have also tried this but it doesn't work.

[image]

and when I try to open the google sign in popup I get this error in the console:
[image]

How can I enable google authentication in the deployed app?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Firebase
2. Go to console
3. Open your project
4. Go to Authentication
5. sign-in-method
6. Add domain

Try it!

In my case it's working